# Zend: How to add Decorators to a form element while using addElement() as a factory?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

As the title implies, I have a question concerning decorators in the Zend Framework. Please consider the following code example:

```
$this->addElement('select', 'DisplayUntil', array(
    'label' => 'Display until:',
    'multiOptions' => $this->getOptions(),
    'filters' => array(
        'HTMLEntities',
        'StringTrim',
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        'Int',
    ),
));
```

This is my preferred method for adding elements to a form. In attempting to establish best practices, I have standardized on using factory methods rather than method chaining. Why? I personally find it much more readable and it shortens the length of my custom form class, i.e. less coding. The above example works beautifully, however, I am having a hard time locating documentation or examples where the same method is used for adding decorators. So using the same code snippet, I assumed when adding decorators you would do the following:

```
$this->addElement('select', 'DisplayUntil', array(
    'label' => 'Display until:',
    'multiOptions' => $this->getOptions(),
    'filters' => array(
        'HTMLEntities',
        'StringTrim',
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        'Int',
    ),
    'decorators' => array(
        'ViewHelper', 
        'Label' => array(
            'tag' => 'dt'
        ),
        'HtmlTag' => array(
            'tag' => 'div',
            'openOnly' => true,
            'id' => 'divDisplayUntil',
            'placement' => 'prepend',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Unfortunately I receive a "Plugin by name 'Dt' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_Form_Decorator_: Zend/Form/Decorator/" error message. I am fairly new to Zend and I would appreciate it if someone could show me how to make the preceding code example work? Is this method even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators seem to have one more layer of arrays. This is from the 1.1x manual:

```
$this->addDecorators(array(
    array('ViewHelper'),
    array('Errors'),
    array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description')),
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd')),
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
));
```

So in your case try

```
'decorators' => array(
    array('ViewHelper'), 
    array('Label', array(
        'tag' => 'dt'
        )
    ),
    array('HtmlTag', array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'openOnly' => true,
        'id' => 'divDisplayUntil',
        'placement' => 'prepend',
        )
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Pity, that just makes things look untidy, however, it does work.

Comment: Yes, rather strange to require such nesting, maybe there is a case where it is needed.